# Natbib: merging author(s) with the same name(s)

Tags: citing, natbib

I defined the following command in my manuscript:

```
\newcommand{\citesep}[2]{\citeauthor{#1}#2~\cite{#1}}
```

which allows me to print, for instance, "Knuth and Tarjan's algorithm [16]" using `\citesep{knuth-681}{'s algorithm}`.

However, this causes an unwanted behaviour with papers with the same authors; for example, `\citesep{knuth-681,knuth-702}{'s work}` produces "Knuth and Tarjan, Knuth and Tarjan's work [16,17]" whereas I'd like it to print "Knuth and Tarjan's work [16,17]".

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You could always just write out the names once and then `\cite` the papers normally after that. Otherwise, biblatex might have the resources to deal with this problem. [Are you sure the authors' names are _exactly_ the same in the two fields? If one is "D. Knuth" and the other is "Donald Knuth", that will cause them to be treated as different...

Comment: Yes, author names are exactly the same. `\citet` does compress them appropriately, I guess a solution could therefore be obtained by modifying it so as to remove reference numbers, but I've had a look at natbib.sty and I don't really see how to do that.

Comment: Can you try IEEE bibtex styles? I'm pretty sure they do that.

Comment: Oddly enough, neither `ieeetr.bst` nor `ieeepes.bst` prints any  names using my `\citesep` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally came up with what seems like a solution. I did the following:

- Dig into `natbib.sty` in search for the macro segment that is responsible for typesetting the author's name(s). Trial and error revealed that `\NAT@nm` does the "raw" typesetting and in turn is formatted by `\NAT@nmfmt`.
- Redefine `\NAT@nmfmt` so that it will additionally typeset the expansion of the new `\nameadjunct` command (which does nothing by default).
- Define the new commands `\citeposs` and `\citesep` which are wrappers for `\citet` but will locally redefine `\nameadjunct` to "'s" respectively `\citesep`'s second mandatory argument.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\newcommand*{\nameadjunct}{\relax}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\NAT@nmfmt}[1]{\NAT@up #1\nameadjunct}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\citeposs}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\nameadjunct}{'s}%
  \citet[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\citesep}[3][]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\nameadjunct}{#3}%
  \citet[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Knu01,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E. and Tarjan, Robert E.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {A new algorithm},
}
@misc{Knu02,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E. and Tarjan, Robert E.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {More about our algorithm},
}\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citet{Knu01,Knu02}

\citeposs{Knu01,Knu02}

\citesep{Knu01,Knu02}{'s algorithm}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't comprehend natbib's intricacies, but here's a solution using [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html). (Note: My `\citesep` command works well for simultaneously citing several papers with the same author(s), but will yield strange results for different authors.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\makeatletter

% COPIED FROM \newbibmacro*{textcite}
\newbibmacro*{textadjunctcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\cbx@tempa
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
%       {\printnames{labelname}}% DELETED
       {\printnames{labelname}% NEW
       \printfield{adjunct}}% NEW
     \addspace\bibopenbracket}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}}

% COPIED FROM \DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textadjunctcite}
  {\let\cbx@tempa=\empty
   \undef\cbx@lasthash}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
%   \usebibmacro{textcite}}% DELETED
   \usebibmacro{textadjunctcite}}% NEW
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \bibclosebracket}

\newcommand*{\citeposs}[2][]{%
  \def\abx@field@adjunct{'s}%
  \textadjunctcite[#1]{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\citesep}[3][]{%
  \def\abx@field@adjunct{#3}%
  \textadjunctcite[#1]{#2}%
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Knu01,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E. and Tarjan, Robert E.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {A new algorithm},
}

@misc{Knu02,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E. and Tarjan, Robert E.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {More about our algorithm},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

This was \citeposs{Knu01,Knu02} work~\dots

As shown in \citesep{Knu01,Knu02}{'s algorithm}~\dots

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Extended MWE to include a `\citeposs` command.

Comment: Just for the reader's reference, there is a similar post devoted to biblatex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22273