# Get "Wilson and Milton's (2010) work..." using BibTex

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, citing

I'm using BibTex to write an academic paper, and want to write something along the lines of:

> Wilson and Milton's (2010) work showed that...

How can I do this when using BibTex with `natbib`. I've tried using the optional arguments to `\citet{}` to put things before and after the citation, but that just puts bits inside the brackets.

I assume I need to use `\citet{}` not `\citep{}`, but is there a way to get it to do this?

Comment: Chicago avoids your construction, saying that the author–date construction refers to the work, not the person.  Better would be "Wilson and Milton (2010) showed that..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like AUTHORS-SOMESTUFF-DATEORREF. I defined the following command:

```
\newcommand{\citesep}[2]{\citeauthor{#1}#2~\cite{#1}}
```

It's not perfect (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/natbib-merging-authors-with-the-same-names)), but it's a start.

Comment: @robintw, @Anthony: I have provided an [additional answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/natbib-merging-authors-with-the-same-names/6636#6636).