# Bibtex in-text citation using "et al." How do you insert 's to indicate possession?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, citing

I'm citing an in-text reference using natbib and a Harvard-style. The way I've constructed the sentence indicates possession, for example:

> Smith et al.'s (2009) recent study ...

What I get when using `\citet{}` is:

> Smith et al. (2009) recent study ...

Is there a way to add the apostrophe and s in this context? I tried placing it in the square brackets `\citet[][]{}` but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can always rewrite; "The recent study by Smith et al. (2009)..."

Comment: True, but in something the length of a dissertation it's nice to be able to vary the sentence structure.

Comment: See also the answers to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/natbib-merging-authors-with-the-same-names) question.

Comment: Very similar concept to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not exactly pretty (especially if you're using hyperlinks or backreferences), but you could use `\citeauthor{key}'s \citeyearpar{key}`.

If you do this a lot you could define a command:

`\newcommand{\citetapos}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyearpar{#1}}`

That way you could avoid having to insert the key twice.

Comment: That's great frabjous, thanks a lot. I added some text color to make the apostrophe blend in with the rest of the hyperlink:             \newcommand{\citetapos}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{'s}} \citeyearpar{#1}}

Comment: Just be careful using this with authors whose names end with 's'.

Comment: Good point - it would be better to deal with those 'manually' - using separate /citeauthor and \citeyearpar commands.

Comment: I don't see the problem. It is perfectly acceptable to add 's to proper names ending in s. In fact, some grammar guides recommend that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Singular_nouns_ending_with_an_.E2.80.9Cs.E2.80.9D_or_.E2.80.9Cz.E2.80.9D_sound

Comment: Fair enough, though I think it looks odd to do that - it's just the way i've been taught. Good to know that it's not a grammatical 'error' at least.

Comment: `citeauthor` and `citeyear` works for me. but for some reason `citeyearpar` does not, giving an error as undefined control sequence. i am using `biblatex`