# bibtex and genitive / possessive 's: the proper way to obtain "Kuran's (1989) model"

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

Is there an automatic way to attach a genitive apostrophe or **"** *'* s **"** to an author's name?

Currently I use:

```
\citeauthor{kuran1989}'s \citeyear{kuran1989}
```

But since this comes up regularily I'd like to know whether there's a general solution.

Comment: You could create a command such as `\possessivecite`, defined as `\newcommand{\possessivecite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}}`. The command `\possessivecite` is defined in the `harvard` citation management package, by the way.

Comment: It seems this question has at least two possible duplicates: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6613 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8159

Comment: @Audrey Let's make the present one the original.

Comment: @ebosi Biblatex version : [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22273/author-name-of-textcite-as-possessive/634495#634495](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22273/author-name-of-textcite-as-possessive/634495#634495)

Comment: Biblatex variant : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22273/author-name-of-textcite-as-possessive/634495#634495

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're using the `natbib` package, a possessive citation command should behave very much like the textual citation command `\citet`. This can be done by altering the name formatting command `\NAT@nmfmt` in the definition for `\citet`. One catch with this approach is that numeric styles don't apply `\NAT@nmfmt`, but you can make them do so by patching `\NAT@test` via the `etoolbox` package. (`\NAT@test` is a command used by the numeric styles to print textual citation labels.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

% make numeric styles use name format
\patchcmd{\NAT@test}{\else \NAT@nm}{\else \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}{}{}

% define \citepos just like \citet
\DeclareRobustCommand\citepos
  {\begingroup
   \let\NAT@nmfmt\NAT@posfmt% ...except with a different name format
   \NAT@swafalse\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue
   \@ifstar{\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@citetp}{\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@citetp}}

\let\NAT@orig@nmfmt\NAT@nmfmt
\def\NAT@posfmt#1{\NAT@orig@nmfmt{#1's}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{companion,
  author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location = {Reading, Mass.},
  year = {1994}}
@book{adams:life,
  title = {Life, the Universe and Everything},
  author = {Adams, Douglas},
  series = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year = {1980}}
@book{adams:rest,
  title = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author = {Douglas Adams},
  series = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year = {1980}}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\textbackslash\texttt{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Compact \cmd{citet}: \citet{adams:life,adams:rest} \\
Compact \cmd{citepos}: \citepos{adams:life,adams:rest} \\
\cmd{citet} with postnote: \citet[pp.~10--20]{companion} \\
\cmd{citepos} with postnote: \citepos[pp.~10--20]{companion} \\
\cmd{citepos*} with postnote: \citepos*[p.~10]{companion}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Loading `natbib` with `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` instead gives:

[image]

In English singular possessive nouns are formed typically by adding "'s", even when the name ends with "s" (e.g. "Adams's"). If the possessive should reflect pronunciation (i.e. "Adams'") you can extend the definition of `\NAT@posfmt` using the `xstring` package.

```
...
\usepackage{xstring}
...
\makeatletter
...
\def\NAT@posfmt#1{%
  \StrRemoveBraces{#1}[\NAT@temp]%
  \IfEndWith{\NAT@temp}{s}
    {\NAT@orig@nmfmt{#1'}}
    {\NAT@orig@nmfmt{#1's}}}

\makeatother
...
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea why this hasn't been integrated into the natbib core package?

Comment: and what about with `biblatex` instead of `natbib`?!

Comment: I'm going to guess because adding `'s` is not valid in some languages? Just a guess though.

Comment: @ebo Check [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22273/31839) out.

Comment: @LondonRob I'm unclear if @ebo meant a direct `biblatex` solution, or instead one for `biblatex` with the `natbib=true` compatibility (which provides e.g. `\citet` from `biblatex`).

Comment: @LeifAndersen, and [Audrey points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22337/109698), this behavior isn't even 100% accurate for English.

Comment: @JasonHemann Sure. Although have you ever seen a paper that cited someone in the plural? I guess maybe if they have the same last name and the author was being a bit informal? e.g. The Cousots' (2014) work clearly indicates .... ?

Comment: Oh! I hadn't even considered possessive plural forms! Good point! I was thinking about the [oddball singular possessive forms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-happens-to-names-when-we-make-them-plural-or-possessive). As far as I know "right" for those comes down to dictated style or personal preference. But I'd think it a shame to switch styles only for citations, or for LaTeX macros to force a writing style. I suppose Socrates' work doesn't come up much in abstract interpretation, so it's probably just a corner case.

Comment: @David Carlisle, would it be possible to modify `\citepos` above to support an unbreakable space between the possessive and citation, e.g., so `Adams` and `[1980a,b]` do not appear on separate lines?

Comment: this gives me syntax errors