# How to put a 's after citing author

Tags: bibtex, citing

So at the moment I have something like:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
%\usepackage{MinionPro}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}



\begin{document}

The most standard approach to modeling default risk centres upon \cite{merton74}'s structural model.

\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

The entry in bibtex is:

```
@article{merton74,
    author  = "Merton, R.",
    title   = "{``On the Pricing of Corporate Debt: The Risk Structure of Interest Rates''}",
    year    = "1974",
    journal = "The Journal of Finance",
    volume  = "29",
    number  = "",
    pages   = "449--470"}
```

The output is like:

[image]

However I would like the 's to appear right after Merton, ie, Merton's (1974).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE.

Comment: Duplicate of [bibtex and genitive: the proper way to obtain "Kuran's (1989) model"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125690) or [Author name of \textcite as possessive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22273).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion the easiest way is too define a new command with the possibilities of `natbib`. The package provides the commands `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{merton74,
    author  = "Merton, R.",
    title   = "{``On the Pricing of Corporate Debt: The Risk Structure of Interest Rates''}",
    year    = "1974",
    journal = "The Journal of Finance",
    volume  = "29",
    number  = "",
    pages   = "449--470"}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\newcommand\cites[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s\ (\citeyear{#1})}
\begin{document}

The most standard approach to modeling default risk centres upon \cites{merton74} structural model.

\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very useful.
I added another command based on Marco's for multiple authors.
`\newcommand\citesall[1]{\citeauthor*{#1}'s\ (\citeyear{#1})}`