# How to cite authors in small cap with \citet?

Tags: formatting, citing, natbib, small-caps

I followed [Natbib reference sheet](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) and `\citet` works as expected. I would like the author's name to appear in small caps, how can I do that?

I guess I should do:

> Define `\citenumfont` to be a font declaration or command like
>   `\itshape` or [...] `\textit`.

but I have no idea what it means.

**Before you upvote lockstep's answer**: it does not work, the authors name are not in small cap, the renewcommand has no effect. His example code does not compile as it is now.

**UPDATE:** Here is a minimum working example.

smallcap.tex

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\NAT@nmfmt}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\def\NAT@nmfmt#1{\textsc{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
As mentioned in \citet{Biegler97}~\dots
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{dummy}
\end{document}
```

dummy.bib

```
@BOOK{biegler97,
  AUTHOR = {Lorenz T. Biegler and Ignacio E. Grossmann and Arthur W. Westerberg},
  TITLE = {Systematic Methods of Chemical Process Design},
  YEAR = {1997},
  PUBLISHER = {Prentice Hall PTR, Upper Saddle River, NJ}
}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\citenumfont}{\textsc}` after loading **natbib**

Comment: @egreg I tried but nothing happened. I recompiled everything properly.

Comment: Please, show a minimal example.

Comment: @egreg Done. Neither of the answers work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the `numbers` option the patch is slightly more complicated:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\NAT@test}{\else\NAT@nm}{\else\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}{}{}
\let\NAT@up\scshape
\makeatother
```

Apparently **natbib**'s author forgot to apply `\NAT@nmfmt` in the relevant place of `\NAT@test`

In order to get `et al.` in roman type,

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,xstring}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\NAT@test}{\else\NAT@nm}{\else\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}{}{}
\renewcommand{\NAT@nmfmt}{\expandafter\aliNAT@nmfmt\expandafter}
\newcommand\aliNAT@nmfmt[1]{{%
  \noexpandarg
  \def~{}%
  \edef\temp#1\edef\temp{\detokenize\expandafter{\temp}}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\StrSubstitute{\temp}{\detokenize{etal}}}\x
    {\textnormal{et\nobreakspace al}}[\tempa]%
  \textsc{\tempa}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it turns et al. also in small cap but it shouldn't do so... :( See my example code.

Comment: +1 and thanks, it works. Is it really the simplest solution? I could not have figured that out myself. :(

Comment: @Ali I haven't figured out a simpler solution. Unfortunately, beside the already mentioned oversight, also `et~al.` is hard coded instead of being buried in a macro. :(

Answer (score 9):

To cite authors in small caps, it is *not* necessary to create a new `.bst` file -- instead, redefine the `\NAT@nmfmt` macro which is responsible for formating the author's name. (See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6636/510) answer for other areas of application for `\NAT@nmfmt`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\NAT@nmfmt}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

As mentioned in \citet[99]{Bli74}~\dots

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AlanMunn: `\citenumfont` only works for numbers in numerical citations.

Comment: Is it necessary to load the `etoolbox` package and use that package's `\patchcmd` macro? The command `\def\NAT@nmfmt#1{{\textsc{#1}}}` should work equally well, right (if embedded between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, naturally)?

Comment: @Mico: Actually, it isn't. Stupid me. Answer corrected.

Comment: @lockstep Please check your answer, it does not work, nothing happens to the author name, it is not in small cap. Your example code does not compile as it is now :(

Comment: @Ali: Works for me.

Comment: This doesn't work if you load `natbib` with the `numbers` option, which (now that there's a minimal example) is what Ali is doing.  @Ali You can see now the importance of posting minimal examples with your question.

Comment: @lockstep As Alan says, it does not work because of the numbers option.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, I just did not expect this to be so difficult. I though there would be a 1 line answer.

Comment: @Ali: I can confirm this, and have already tried to find a solution. The `natbib` code internals are a real pain, though. Have you considered to switch to `biblatex`?

Comment: @lockstep OK, thanks for your efforts. I have to collaborate with others using latex and natbib. If I switch to biblatex there will be compatibility issues, right?

Comment: @Ali: Right. :-(

Comment: Thank oul, @lockstep. I, for one, can live with this solution `:-)`. As one tiny improvement, could you add how to exclude "et al." from the capitalization?

Answer (score 4):

From p. 15 of the `natbib` manual:

> Numerical citations may be printed in a different font. Define
>   `\citenumfont` to be a font declaration like `\itshape` or even a command
>   taking arguments like `\textit.` [The command] `\renewcommand{\citenumfont}[1]{\textit{#1}}` ... is better than `\itshape` since it automatically adds italic correction.

Hence, changing `\citenumfont` will not affect the font used by LaTeX for typesetting authors' names in either citations or the bibliography. For that, you need to create a bibliography style file (extension `.bst`), probably from scratch. Have a look at the file [makebst.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/makebst.tex) (created by the author of the `natbib` package, by the way). It can be run under either TeX or LaTeX; when you run it, it'll ask you a lot of questions (with predefined options for answers) about the desired bibliography style -- including some about special fonts for authors' names -- and then builds a .bst file with this information.

**Addendum**: As @lockstep notes in his answer and in a comment to my answer, if you only want to use small-caps for the names of authors/editors in *citations*, it is not strictly necessary to create a new `.bst` file: one could, instead, redefine the `\NAT@nmfmt` macro. However, you must still create a new .bst file if you want the names of authors and editors be typeset in small-caps in the *bibliography section* as well -- **plus** you'll have to remember to insert instructions such as

```
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@nmfmt#1{\textsc{#1}}
\makeatother
```

from now on in the preamble of every document you write that features this citation format. You might as well simply tell the `makebst.tex` program about this preference and be done with it once and for all, right?

Comment: At least for formatting the author's name in citations, one *doesn't* need to create a `.bst` file -- see my answer.

Comment: @lockstep -- good news that one doesn't have to created or modify a .bst file, though the alternative does require extra work as well.

Comment: @Mico +1 and thanks for the response!

Comment: @Mico Your last suggestion does not work :( I am already using similar \def-s in the preamble so another one is no problem. Could you check your last suggestion, please?

Comment: @Ali: Could you be a bit more specific about what "does not work"? I've added a pair of curly braces to the `\def`; please try the new code.

Comment: @Mico It still does not work. By "does not work" I mean it has no effect, the author names are not in small cap.

Comment: @Ali: Hmm, it works for me. :-) Could you recheck the code you use -- there are quite a few braces.

Comment: No it gives a compile error, the error is at \def{: ! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.22 \def{
          \NAT@nmfmt}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

Comment: @Ali: I've changed the (re)definition of `\NAT@nmfmt` slightly -- please try to rerun the code. Remember to run latex/bibtex/latex/latex on your main file.

Comment: @Mico Done. It still has no effect. I deleted everything except the my_file.tex and recompiled everything. Your redefiniton has no effect :(

Comment: @Ali: OK, you should really post a MWE (minimum working example) of your code that replicates the error/no effect you observe. There must be something in your setup that keeps interfering with the commands `\makeatletter \def\NAT@nmfmt#1{\textsc{#1}} \makeatother`. (You do execute this code *after* loading `natbib`, right?)

Comment: @Mico Done, please check my update.