# Italic citation reference for author name using natbib

Tags: formatting, citing, natbib, italic

I'm trying to get italics for the author name within the citation using `natbib` with `agsm` style.

My MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Smith2011,
  author = {Joe Smith},
  title = {The Lord of the Wings},
  year = {2011},
  publisher = {Amazon},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} % natbib used for reference style

\begin{document}
So the following should show the name \citeauthor{Smith2011} in italic \citep{Smith2011}, but it doesn't work?
\bibliographystyle{agsm} % AGSM style matches closely to Brunel style
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

I have to use Harvard style for my report, though when I tried to replace `agsm` with `harvard`, it didn't find the style? I thought it comes with `natbib`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37283/510) to [How to cite authors in small cap with \citet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37194/how-to-cite-authors-in-small-cap-with-citet) and replace `\scshape` with `\itshape`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Smith2011,
  author = {Joe Smith},
  title = {The Lord of the Wings},
  year = {2011},
  publisher = {Amazon},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} % natbib used for reference style

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\NAT@test}{\else\NAT@nm}{\else\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}{}{}
\let\NAT@up\itshape
\makeatother

\begin{document}
So the following should show the name \citeauthor{Smith2011} in italic \citep{Smith2011}, but it doesn't work?
\bibliographystyle{agsm} % AGSM style matches closely to Brunel style
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: `natbib` provides the styles `plainnat`, `abbrvnat`, and `unsrtnat`. The [`harvard`](http://ctan.org/pkg/harvard) *package* provides additional styles that may be used with `natbib`, but no "harvard" *style* .

Comment: is there a way i could just italicise et al part ?